# How to call a function in godot once within a collision?

Tags: collision-detection, godot

I made a script in godot to be an object that will be the xp dropped when the enemy is destroyed and so far everything is working, until the part where when the player collides with the xp object the collision is called several times making the xp of the player being increased instead of 10 in 500, I tried to solve this with if and boolean and it didn't work, I tried using the switch (which in this case is match in gdscript) and it didn't work and my last attempt was to make an array that would save the player's body to check if the player has already collided and it still didn't work. And one more thing, the player is a KinematicBody2D and the XP object is an Area2D and I'm using godot 3.5

```
extends Node


var xp

signal XP(i)

var collided_objects = []

func _on_Node2D_body_entered(body):
    if body.has_method("AddXp") and not collided_objects.has(body):
            collided_objects.append(body)
            connect("XP", body, "AddXp")
            emit_signal("XP", xp)
            queue_free()
    pass
```

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this problem and make the collision call the player's AddXp method once and then destroy the object that is the xp?

Comment: Are you sure you are not spawning multiple of the XP objects (each one correctly colliding and increasing XP only once)?

Comment: That was the problem, I had forgotten to condition the enemy's AI to spawn an XP object once... 2 hours of anger for that